How to moq an object with private member fields and setup the methods of those private objects?
I am using .Net Core 8 and I have the following class:
public class UserRepository : EfRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IJwtFactory _jwtFactory;
    private readonly IJwtTokenValidator _jwtTokenValidator;
    private readonly ITokenFactory _tokenFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ILogger<UserRepository> _logger;
    public UserRepository(ILogger<UserRepository> logger, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, IMapper mapper, AppDbContext appDbContext, IJwtFactory jwtFactory, IJwtTokenValidator jwtTokenValidator, ITokenFactory tokenFactory) : base(appDbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _jwtFactory = jwtFactory;
        _jwtTokenValidator = jwtTokenValidator;
        _tokenFactory = tokenFactory;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async virtual Task<MyResponse> MethodUnderTest(string id)
    {
        _userManager.DoSomeThing(); // Moq'ed object
        _signInManager.DoSomeThins(); // Moq'ed object
    }
}

(1) Should I Moq the IUserRepository or the object? How do I setup the function calls of the private objects UserManager and SignInManager? In fact, how do I pass a Moq of the UserManager and SignInManager to the Moqed IUserInterface?
(2) When I Moq the UserRepository object, I hit the following exception when passing the Moq object to another object under test's constructor:
System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Web.Api.Infrastructure.Data.Repositories.UserRepository.
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
Castle.Proxies.ILogger`1Proxy
Castle.Proxies.UserManager`1Proxy
Castle.Proxies.SignInManager`1Proxy
Castle.Proxies.IMapperProxy
Castle.Proxies.AppDbContextProxy
Castle.Proxies.IJwtFactoryProxy
Castle.Proxies.IJwtTokenValidatorProxy
Castle.Proxies.ITokenFactoryProxy
 (Parameter 'constructorArguments')
---- System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.UserRepositoryProxy' not found.

The objective is to be able to moq all the objects involed in UserRepository method under test with respective methods Setup for test. For that, I have a class fixture which creates all the moqs:
public class InfrastructureTestBase : IDisposable
{
    public Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> UserManager { get; } = new Mock<UserManager<AppUser>>(Mock.Of<IUserStore<AppUser>>(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    public Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>> SignInManager { get; }
    public Mock<ILogger<IUserRepository>> Logger { get; } = new Mock<ILogger<IUserRepository>>();
    public Mock<IMapper> Mapper { get; } = new Mock<IMapper>();
    public Mock<AppDbContext> AppDbContext { get; } = new Mock<AppDbContext>(new DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>());
    public Mock<IJwtFactory> JwtFactory { get; } = new Mock<IJwtFactory>();
    public Mock<IJwtTokenValidator> JwtTokenValidator { get; } = new Mock<IJwtTokenValidator>();
    public Mock<UserRepository> UserRepository { get; private set; }
    public Mock<ITokenFactory> TokenFactory { get; } = new Mock<ITokenFactory>();
    public InfrastructureTestBase()
    {
        SignInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>(UserManager.Object, Mock.Of<IHttpContextAccessor>(), Mock.Of<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>>(), null, null, null, null);
        SignInManager.Setup(i => i.RefreshSignInAsync(It.IsAny<AppUser>()));
        Mapper.Setup(i => i.Map<AppUser, User>(It.IsAny<AppUser>(), It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(new User()); // XXX
        UserRepository = new Mock<UserRepository>(Logger.Object, UserManager.Object, SignInManager.Object, Mapper.Object, AppDbContext.Object, JwtFactory.Object, JwtTokenValidator.Object, TokenFactory.Object);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Following Mark Seemann's answer, I use UserManager as SUT. However, I hit an impediment with IMapper mapping from It.IsAny<AppUser> to It.IsAny<User>. Specifically, the following member method of UserRepository, which is used by most of the methods under test, would throw null exception
private async Task<User> getUser(AppUser appUser) => appUser == null ? null : _mapper.Map<AppUser, User>(appUser, await GetSingleBySpec(new UserSpecification(appUser.Id)));

GetSingleBySpec is an inherited member method of UserRepository.

You should Moq the IUserRepository in any testcase that needs a UserRepository implementation. When you test the UserRepository you moq all its constructor arguments. That you have private types on a public constructor is a code-smell. If you have to, make those classes internal and make those internals visible to the unit-test project. Or have a UserRepositoryFactory class that knows how to create a UserRepository.

Not sure about the "code smell". I have updated my post.

It looks as though you have a follow-up question based on my answer. If so, please create a new post asking that follow-up question. It gets very confusing if you keep moving the goalpost so that the answers are forced to keep up in order to answer another question than the one that was originally asked. Feel free to ping me with a link to the new question.

If you need to write a test of the UserRepository class itself, then you can create Test Doubles of all of its dependencies, just as shown in the OP.
There's no need to create a Mock<UserRepository>, since in that scenario, the UserRepository object is the System Under Test (SUT):
var userRepository = new UserRepository(
    Logger.Object,
    UserManager.Object,
    SignInManager.Object,
    Mapper.Object,
    AppDbContext.Object,
    JwtFactory.Object,
    JwtTokenValidator.Object,
    TokenFactory.Object);
// Test code that exercises userRepository go here; e.g.
var actual = await userRepository.MethodUnderTest("foo");

On the other hand, if you need to test another class that depends on IUserRepository, just create a test double of it:
var userRepositoryTD = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
// Configure one or more interface members if needed:
userRepositoryTD.Setup(r => r.MethodUnderTest("foo")).ReturnsAsync(whatever);
// Now pass the Test Double to your actual SUT
var sut = new MyClass(userRepositoryTD.Object);
// Then add test code that exercises the sut here...

The userRepositoryTD.Object is a dynamically-generated implementation of the IUserRepository interface, and it has nothing else to do with the concrete UserRepository class. Thus, in this case, there's no need to configure any of the UserRepository class' dependencies (userManager, userManager, etc.). The userRepositoryTD.Object doesn't have those dependencies.

How to moq and setup some of the methods of UserRepository?

As Mark stated: userRepositoryTD.Setup(r => r.MethodUnderTest("foo")).ReturnsAsync(whatever);

UserRepository is NOT moqed in this case. It's a SUT.
